# passing a single character to a function in C++

Tags: c++, function

I've searched through the net for my problem and I know that for returning array values from a function to our main function(or any other functions, anyway) I need to use pointers(it can be done in various methods), and I can use them for solving my issue either, however, I'm still curious about why my program behaves in an unanticipated(to me of course!) way, I'm a beginner so please explain in as much detail as you can, here's my tiny program:

```
char Calc(char);

int main(){
    Calc('1');
    return 0;
}

char Calc(char a) {
    a = int(a);
    std::cout << a <<std::endl;
    std::cout << int('1');
    _getch();
    return 'c';
}
```

According to ASCII table, the integer of '1' is 49, so both commands in my *Func* function have to display the same thing, namely 49, but it displays this as the output:

```
1
49
```

What am I missing here? Thanks.

Comment: _"I know that for returning array values from a function to our main function(or any other functions, anyway) I need to use pointers"_ Nooooo don't do that. _"I've searched through the net for my problem"_ Stop being lazy and **read a book** instead of just casually "searching through the net". _"What am I missing here?"_ Study.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to study more, but actually, I did it and it works. May I know why are you against it?

Comment: 80% chance that the pointer is dangling, and when it's not, you are utilising antiquated C idioms with unclear ownership semantics. Sure, "it works", the same way that driving a tuk-tuk down the motorway "works": everything appears to be fine until you're flattened by a lorry, and you won't even see it coming. Return a `std::array` or a `std::vector` either by reference or by value depending on your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time and your instructive simile. Appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
std::cout << a <<std::endl;
```

displays `1` since [`std::basic_ostream& operator<<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) is overloaded for `char`s as a non-member operator and displays their corresponding ASCII values. On the other hand,

```
std::cout << int('1') <<std::endl;
```

displays the `char` `'1'` as an `int` (due to the explicit cast), so you see the corresponding ASCII index of `49` instead. That's because for arithmetic types the member [`std::basic_ostream& operator<<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) is being picked up instead.

Note that your line

```
a = int(a);
```

doesn't do anything, it doesn't change the type of `a` to `int`; it just casts the RHS to `int` then assigns back the `int` to the original `char` (with no loss of data obviously). In C or C++ the type is set in stone at compile time.

Comment: Ah, thanks, my issue is now resolved, but I didn't get the initial part that you talked about overloading, should I go further in my course to understand it?

Comment: @M-J In C++ you can overload operators or functions, that is, have an operator/function defined have the same name but different definitions for different types. In your case, `<<` is a shorthand for `operator<<`, and the later has a special definition for `char`s alone (as a [non-member `operator<<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2)), so the `char` is displayed as a `char` and not an ASCII index. When you do the cast, the **other** member overload is being picked up which simply displays the ASCII index.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `a = int(a);`, You cast promote `char` to `int`. But after you assign this result to a. So you cast `int` to `char`, this could loss data.

But in fact you just say `'1' = int('1')`, so you did nothing. Try `a = int(42000)`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help, What am I supposed to learn by doing this? a = int(42000)

Comment: @M-J That a will be not equal to 42000 but `42000 % (2**(sizeof int * CHAR_BIT))`

Answer (score 0):

a is char so assigning int to a will assign the character value of ASCII code of character `1`:

```
char a = (int)a;// a = '1' (int)a = (int)'1' = 49 so the result is: 
a = (char)49 = 1; // because assigning an integer to char will implicitly convert it.

cout << (int)'1'; or int i = (int)'1';
the ASCII value of character '1' is as we said below is 49
cout << i; // 49
```